# GRUB Issues with ubuntu 16.04 64-bit software RAID 1 install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, grub, raid-1

I am installing Ubuntu 16.04 on a 1u using a software RAID1. I've done this many times with previous ubuntu releases but for some reason 16.04 doesn't like my software RAID1. I've reconfigured it many times and still nothing. This is a clean install of ubuntu 16.04. GRUB doesn't seem to install correctly for some reason although During the installation, it seems to install correctly with no errors. The progress bar and status output seems to be normal. It installs the bootloader on sda and sdb which are my 2 RAID1 drives. After the install, I restart my computer and all it says is: /dev/md1p1: clean, 60667/4768677........ on a black screen with a blinking white cursor on the bottom of that one line. It's just stuck. Has anybody else had this issue? I've read multiple forums about this and a lot of people say its a bug. unfortunately I can't seem to fix this. I've tried making a 250MB fat32 partition on both HDDs so the bootloader could be installed there as suggested by an Ubuntu expert but that did not work.

Comment: This does not sound like a grub issue - it seems that instead of treating md1 as a partition the configuration has partitioned it  into blocks. Have you tried configuring LVM on RAID to get past this?